# Implementing EntityFramework 5 in to Solution

Tags: entity-framework

In my solution I have more than 40 projects. I just want to confirm something that, if I have used a common entity for all my project will degrade the performance or I have to use the separate Entity(ObjectContext) for each project.

Which one is better..?

Can anyone help me..?

Thanks.

Comment: Tough to answer this one but in short it may be difficult for the purposes of unit testing without a single context/repo. For that purpose along I would investigate single context. in my case it is rare that I don't use a "project.core" where all my entities reside as well as generic repository logic.

Comment: 40 projects sounds like a bit of a code smell to me, prehaps you need to split it into a few solutions?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.! I am working in a large industry and we have a Core Project to 'Handle' all the project inside the Solution. In my case I have only one fear that If I implemented only one Entity for the all Project it will reduce the Query performance..? || The Initialization in multiple time will take time .? || Will I face any Caching issue..? Thanks again for your consideration! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you take a look at [Bounded Contexts article by Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532098.aspx?sdmr=JulieLerman)

Large contexts can be inefficient. But worse is contexts with too many entries at once.
You can have 1 DAL/EF project with contexts that address Business areas/spaces.

These could and should be reused across your projects.

I would use 1 large Context for Migration/Initial DB creation and the bounded contexts for day to day access.

Business process would dictate which context was loaded/accessed